# How to concatenate variable with array element

Tags: bash, npm

What I want to achieve is to automatically install NPM packages, so I created a separate variable which holds `"sudo npm install"` and iterating over an array which has the package name.
Facing error that command not found but if I put it into the console it works.

```
npm_base='sudo npm install '
npm_scripts=("-g eslint")

for element in ${npm_scripts[@]}
do
    ${npm_base}${element}
done
```

Comment: Why don't you just put `npm install` in the `crontab` for root?

Comment: how exactly will crontab help? It just scheduling commands

Comment: Where do you get the "command not found" error?

Comment: What is the exact error? Which package not found?

Comment: With your command I get `npm ERR! addLocal Could not install [...]`, instead of `command not found`

Comment: Which shell do you run this script in?

Answer (score 2):

You're very close.

You need to add double quotes around the array, otherwise `-g` and `eslint` will be separated.

```
npm_base='sudo npm install'
npm_scripts=("-g eslint")

for element in "${npm_scripts[@]}"
do
    ${npm_base} ${element}
done
```

See https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/bash-for-loop-array/

Comment: getting an error in "sudo npm install" for the line inside loop

Comment: For me it works. Maybe you start telling us the exact error, instead of telling us that there is an error.

Comment: already posted error:   `command not found: sudo npm install`

Comment: So is `npm` definitely installed on your system @Andrew. Can you run the command directly from the cli?

Comment: yes, i actually solved this just using command + array element `sudo npm install  ${element}`